# How would I retrieve certain information on a webpage using their ID value?

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net, I can download a webpage as a string like this:

```
    Using ee As New System.Net.WebClient()
        Dim reply As String = ee.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/eHcQRiff")
        MessageBox.Show(reply)
    End Using
```

Would it be possible to specify an ID tag of an item on the webpage so that the reply will only output the information inside of the code box/id tag?

Example:

The ID tag of `RAW Paste Data` on `https://pastebin.com/eHcQRiff` is `id="paste_code"` which includes the following text:

```
Test=1
Test=2
```

Is there anyway to get the `WebClient` to only output that exact same message using the ID tag (or any other method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HtmlAgilityPack library

```
Dim document as HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
document.Load(@"C:\YourDownloadedHtml.html")

Dim text as string = document.GetElementbyId("paste_code").InnerText
```

Some more sample code:
(Tested with HtmlAgilityPack 1.6.10.0)

```
Dim html As string = "<TD width=""""50%""""><DIV align=right>Name :<B> </B></DIV></TD><TD width=""""50%""""><div id='i1'>SomeText</div></TD><TR vAlign=center>"
Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html) 'To load from html string directly
Dim name As String = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td/div[@id='i1']").InnerText
Console.WriteLine(name)
```

> Output:
>   SomeText

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sunil!, Do you have any ideas on how to do this without adding external libraries?  I'd prefer not having additional dll's with my program :/

Comment: Without external library, you can do it using either [HtmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3) or [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) parsing. With HtmlDocument the could would be nearly similar

Comment: Figured it out using the built in WebBrowser, thanks for the help!